# How to differentiate function asp vs asa

Tags: asp-classic

How to differentiate function of asp file and asa file(not global.asa, other name file) in classic asp project.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  Classic ASP only recognizes global.asa

Comment: The asa file extension is work as asp file Whatever name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asa files are also seen as visual interdev files but will never be confused with asp files from the IIS standpoint.  As @Dee states classic asp only reads the global.asa.

The ASA file type is primarily associated with 'Active Server' not to be confused with ASP which is 'Active Server Pages'.  Visual Interdev was a programming IDE in the late 90's.  ASP is a scripting language that will render similar to HTML with scripting abilities.

In short you shouldn't have to differentiate them unless your using visual interdev as your IDE and in that case you might want to upgrade to notepad++ or textpad as you'll probably get better intellisense and support.